# Assets Audio file can not play in Expo

Tags: reactjs, react-native, expo

```
import AlphService from './AlphService';

export default class MyClass extends React.Component {
 alphService;
 constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  alphService = new AlphService();
  this.state = alphService.getState();
 }
 componentWillMount() {
    this.play(this.state.sound);
  }

  play(source) {
   console.log(source);
   Audio.setIsEnabledAsync(true);
   const sound = new Audio.Sound();
   const play_sound = (async () => {
    await sound.loadAsync(require(source)); //Error Here
    await sound.playAsync();
   })();
  }
}
```

AlphService.js

```
export default class alphService {
 stateObj = {
  sound: ""
 };
 getState(){
  this.stateObj.sound = "../assets/sounds/c.mp3"; 
  return this.stateObj;
 }
}
```

> ERROR: components/Alphabet.js:Invalid call at line 51: require(source)

and also try 
I return `require(soundPathVar)` object from `getState()` method and remove required from `play()`, then same error.

I am beginner in react-native and I want to try creating a dynamic sound file path. So can you please help me if I am doing wrong. Thank in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I faced this when i was trying to `require` dynamic images, it turned out that `require` only accepts specific source even `require("SOURCE/" + "something.png")` doesn't work, it should be `require("SOURCE/something.png")`. Try this:

```
export default class alphService {
 stateObj = {
  sound: ""
 };
 getState(){
  this.stateObj.sound = require("../assets/sounds/c.mp3"); 
  return this.stateObj;
 }
}
```

You can create a json file containing all paths and use it like so:

```
export default const paths = {
    file1: require("path/to/file1.png"),
    file2: require("path/to/file2.png")
}
```

then in your component import this paths file and use it like so (for example an image):

```
<Image source={paths.file1}/>
```

Comment: yes its work, because is static path to require. dynamic path is not possible?

Comment: Dynamic path is unfortunately not possible yeah, if you want you can create a json file containing all paths then you can use import this file and use it, I'll update my answer with an example